# Authorize.net Login fails

Tags: android, authorize.net

This is the first time I am working on authorize.net payment gateway.
I am developing one android application which requires authorize.net.
I have downloaded code sample from

https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-android

in this code when I try to login with my sandbox credentials it is not allowing me to login. there is one "LoginActivity.java" file which contains "deviceID" field. i don't know from where to get this device id. There is one comment as well like "set your_device_ID. You need to get a registered device id from your MINT account and set the id here"

so my question is what is MINT Account? 
is there any other parameters we need to set?

Comment: https://www.mint.com/ or https://cardservicing.mint.co.uk/RBSG_Consumer/Login.do?promoCode=Mint

Comment: @Skizo can you please explain me why this mint device id is required in authorize.net ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id?rq=1

Comment: I also wont get login...any solution ?

Comment: MINT here mean the Merchant Interface : URL for development purpose : https://sandbox.authorize.net/